# How to integrate Google Docs editor in Vue web App

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

My Vue web app has the feature of uploading, editing, and downloading the files, We are using Azure Blob storage to store the files.

Now I want to load the Azure Blob file in Google Docs Editor, so that user can view/edit/save the content of the files, like how it is done in Box. But i didn't find any useful documentation or sites which describes the flow to implement it.
Can anyone please suggest me the way to proceed?